# Different behavior in BASH with 'export' in a script depending on if it is source from within a BASH function

Tags: bash

I have two files, `someOtherScript.bash`:

```bash
export SOME_VARIABLE='SOME OTHER VALUE'
```

And `foo.bash`:

```bash
SOME_VARIABLE="good value"

function foo() {
  echo "  before source ($SOME_VARIABLE)"
  SOME_VARIABLE='' source ./someOtherScript.bash
  echo "  after source ($SOME_VARIABLE)"
}

echo "Called from the top of the script:"
echo "  before source ($SOME_VARIABLE)"
SOME_VARIABLE='' source ./someOtherScript.bash
echo "  after source ($SOME_VARIABLE)"

echo
echo "Now, done from within a function:"
foo $@
```

Note that the three lines of code from within the function match the three lines of code outside of it.  Yet when I run `./foo` this is the output I get:

```
Called from the top of the script:
  before source (good value)
  after source (good value)

Now, done from within a function:
  before source (good value)
  after source (SOME OTHER VALUE)
```

What's going on here? I wouldn't expect the behavior to differ based on whether I was inside a function or not?

Comment: FYI this is version dependent. I can't reproduce it on a Mac running bash 3.2, but I can on Linux running 5.1.

Comment: Strange. FWIW, I'm running version 4.4.19(1) on my system. And (maybe less surprisingly) I see totally different behavior if using zsh (5.9) on a mac (then the exported variable makes it "out" of the sourced script the first time its invoked).

Comment: Reproducible running bash 5.2 (on MacOS, but I don't think that the OS matters here).

Comment: I don't have an explanation, why this happens differently inside a function than on top-level. Could be a bug in bash. After all, it is very unusual that one prefixes the `source` command with an assignment, and it could well be that this never has been tested properly. Perhaps you could file this as bug to the bash developers?

Comment: Since you also tested it with zsh, I tried it with my zsh (5.8.1), and I see "good value" in all cases, inside and outside the function. I don't know whether this is correct or wrong behaviour. On the one hand, `source` is supposed to be executed in the current shell and hence should change the variable, but prefixing a command with an assignment means that the command is run in its own environment, which means that after execution, `SOME_VARIABLE` needs to be restored to the value it had before. This is obviously done correctly by zsh.